# Short dynamic link but in an appropriate way Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to generate a link, but in an appropriate way:
like
`https://<host-name>.page.link/post?id=63aade7d6f1407003522010a&title=Post Title`

When I generate a long link it appears this way :

```
https://<host-name>.page.link?afl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.page.link%2Fblog%2Fpost%3Fid%3D63aade7d6f1407003522010a%26title%3DBlog&apn=<package-name>&ibi=<package-name>=https%3A%2F%2Fshahbndr.page.link%2Fblog%2Fpost%3Fid%3D63aade7d6f1407003522010a%26title%3DBlog
```

When I generate a short link it appears this way :

```
https://<host-name>.page.link/AaTt
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: How are you generating these values?

Comment: by firebase-dynamic-links

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

This is a current limitation in FDL. There's an existing feature request on having an option to customize your short links via [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest). I added a vote on the request to let the team know about the demand for such a feature.

I won’t be able to share timelines as to when the feature will be available in our APIs. You can check our [official blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/) and [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) from time to time for further updates.